# Whenever the first number is bigger it doesnt work

Tags: java

When i put the first number bigger than the second number the program doesn't output anything it is just blank.

```
import javax.swing.*;                                                           //for JFrame and JPanel
import java.text.*;                                                             //for text

public class number6{                                                           //states class name

    public static void main (String [] args){                                   //starts program

        String firstStr, secondStr;                                             //states string variables
        int first, second;                                                      //states integer variables

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");

        firstStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter first number:");    //asks for first number
        first = Integer.parseInt(firstStr);                                     //makes first number from string to integer

        secondStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter second number:");  //asks for second number
        second = Integer.parseInt(secondStr);                                   //makes second nubmer from string to integer

        for(int x = first; x <= second; x++){
            if(first != 0){                                                     //doesn't show 0
                System.out.print(x + " ");                      //output statement
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This is unreadable and only makes it harder for you.

Comment: "the program doesn't work" -- Can you explain what that means? Are you getting an error message? Does your keyboard catch on fire? Are the waffles burnt?

Comment: What do you expect it to do if the first number is larger?

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `x = first` and then *increasing* `x` for as long as `x` is less than or equal to `second`. If `first>second`, this condition will never be met.

You need to make sure you're iterating from the lowest value to the largest:

```
for(int x = Math.min(first, second); x <= Math.max(first, second); x++)
```